# how to convert object into array of objects (or collection of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, lodash

Searched and searched, can't find this, but I'm assuming it's easy.

I'm looking for the lodash "object" equivalent of lodash [_.pairs()](https://lodash.com/docs#pairs) - but I want an array of objects (or a collection of objects).

Example:

```
// Sample Input
{"United States":50, "China":20}

// Desired Output
[{"United States":50}, {"China":20}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using lodash, this is one way of generating the expected result:

```
var res = _.map(obj, _.rearg(_.pick, [2,1]));
```

The above short code snippet can be confusing. Without using the `_.rearg` function it becomes:

```
_.map(obj, function(v, k, a) { return _.pick(a, k); });
```

Basically the `rearg` function was used for reordering the passed arguments to the `pick` method.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what the OP wanted. Thanks!

Comment: this is the correct answer to this question, but if you use this in my code base without a 10 line comment, I will kick you. I can look at @HunanRostomyan's code and tell you exactly what it does without much thought

Comment: @mkoryak - indeed, lots of lodash function chains require comments, otherwise it's virtually nonsensical! (I'm finding this to be true of Angular also).

Comment: @cale_b, to use the code in `chain` you need to add it as a [mixin](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin).

Comment: @andy - I was able to make it work in a chain without `mixin` - `_.chain(data).map(function(v,k,a) {return _.pick(a,k);});`

Answer (score 6):

Would something like this be sufficient? It's not lodash, but...

```
var input = {"United States":50, "China":20};
Object.keys(input).map(function(key) {
  var ret = {};
  ret[key] = input[key];
  return ret;
});
//=> [{"United States":50}, {"China":20}]
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I'm going to wait and see if a lodash option comes up - this project is fairly committed to using lodash if possible.

Comment: lodash is helper lib, you dont need to use it if your language natively supports the thing you are trying to do :P

Comment: @cale_b All javascript is lodash, but trivially, of course.

Comment: @mkoryak - Understood.  But, if I have lodash loaded, and I can complete this in a single function line such as `_.pairs()`, and use it in my [_.chain()](https://lodash.com/docs#chain), then using the *lodash* method makes far more sense than for me to write this function and call it separately.  Are you suggesting it's not available in lodash?

Comment: @cale_b Vohuman has provided exactly the solution you were looking for!

Answer (score 1):

ok, if you must:

```
var input = {"United States":50, "China":20};
var ouput = _.map(input, function(val, key){ var o = {}; o[key] = val; return o; });
```

but this is not better than the previous answer. its worse.

Comment: You are right, it's not better.  While I know I could use `_.map` to do about anything, what I'm asking is if there's a version equivalent to `_.pairs()` that I'm missing....

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one!

Comment: @mkoryak: care to check qtip question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125268/how-to-enable-qtip2-in-piechart-made-by-plottable-js-d3-js